# Apahce/.htaccess - Redirect all requests to a single page except assets used by that page

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> Working in LAMP stack environment, I have the following issue.
>
> I would like to have all request made to Apache to return a specific page (i.e. all >request will return fixing.php). However fixing.php itself requests a couple of assets >(images, css files) to appear correctly.

**Example:**

*From Apache's point of view, the user requests:*
**apple.html**

*Apache using .htaccess redirectMatch returns*
**fixing.php**

As fixing.php renders on the browser, the browser request two assets style.css and background.jpg. However Apache recieves these reqeuest and still just returns fixing.php (hence you get a loop).

How does one configure an .htaccess file do this?

I've tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /fixed.php [L,R=301]
```

On the basis that the only files that existed were the fixed.php, and the style.css file  - by my logic - if the requested file is not a file (i.e doesn't exist) or a directory that's reqeusted isn't there - return fixed.php

Comment: Do you really want to redirect to `fixed.php`? or simply rewrite to it?  In other words, should the browser still show `apple.html`?

Comment: Redirect, it shouldn't display apple.html, or banana.html or cherry.html, any request should return fixed.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !fixed\.php
RewriteRule ^ /fixed.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.